# Order By (from value on another DB)

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

i have a little probleme and i not found a solution.

i have 2 database > Name and Category

in the DB name its like :

```
ID NAme   Cat_Id
1  Viskor 2
2  House  1
3  mouse  1
4  Charlie 2
5  One     3
```

and category db is :

```
ID  Cat_Name
1   Word
2   User
3   Number
```

how is possible to display the list name order by name ASC from my category db?

actually i only can order by Cat_ID but is not alphabetic.

sory for my basic english and mistake ^^

Comment: post your sql query to rectify

Comment: Depending upon your sql statement you should be able to do ORDER BY Cat_Name

Comment: Is you mean table? Not different db(database)?  If so you can use. Select * from name n, category c where c.id = n.cat_id. Order by c.cat_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM name n INNER JOIN category c ON n.Cat_Id = c.ID ORDER BY cat_Name ASC
```

SELECT (YOUR_REQUIRED_SET_OF_FIELDS)

Comment: work perfectly => '$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table n INNER JOIN cat c ON n.categorie = c.ID ORDER BY Name ASC";'

Answer (score 0):

Try this one sir:

```
SELECT n.ID, n.NAme, n.Cat_Id, CAT_NAME
FROM Name n
INNER JOIN Category c
ON n.ID=c.ID ORDER BY c.NAme ASC;
```

Comment: Yes is one Database with 2 different table

My original request is : 
`code` $sql = "SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY cat_id ASC"; `code`

and the trying request => dont work
`code` $sql = "SELECT * FROM nameWHERE cat.id=name.categorie ORDER BY cat.name ASC";`code`